# Aggregate Keras loss function over each element of output tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a `custom_loss_function(y_true, y_predicted)`. Due to extern algebraic library restrictions this function only works, if `y_true` and `y_predicted` are both 6D-vectors. My output tensor has a `(batch_count, element_count, 6)` shape and I would like to apply `custom_loss_function` element-wise across the final axis of `y_true` and `y_predicted` and then aggregate them with some function e.g. mean.

I found `tf.map_fn(...)`/`keras.backend.map_fn(...)`, but those only operate on axis 0. I also tried concatenating first across the batches like so:

```py
def mean_custom_loss(true_output, predicted_output):
    batches = (keras.backend.concatenate(true_output, 0)), (keras.backend.concatenate(predicted_output, 0))
    return keras.backend.mean(keras.backend.map_fn(lambda x: custom_loss_function(x[1], x[0]), batches, dtype='float32'))
```

but this does not seem to work either, as the batches are handled internally by Keras and cannot be properly worked on. In that case `keras.backend.concatenate` throws me *TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled.*

It could be something obvious that I am missing. Is there a simple way to get the job done and apply `custom_loss_function` element-wise on the final axis of my output?

Comment: if your issue here is that you need to change axes 2 to 0 you can try: ```arr.transpose(2,0,1).shape```

Comment: There is nothing we can do without the function. Usually you don't need to do anything at all for the function to be applied elementwise. But without seeing the function there isn't a way to provide an answer.

Comment: @DanielMöller This topic is about applying a loss function element-wise. What the function is shouldn't be relevant here, as it would make the problem statement more complex than it really is. All you need to know is that it does not work on multi-dimensional tensors, otherwise this problem would not exist to begin with. If you really need a sample function just think of anything with direct index access.

Comment: I was really trying to help. And to my Keras knowledge, yes, we need the function. Any regular Keras function that is not a reduction function operates elementwise, so, this is your answer.

Comment: @DanielMöller Well, thanks for trying to help, but I prefer an answer to the actual problem instead of a confirmation that it does not work. I highly doubt it will help anybody but the used loss function is defined at https://github.com/geomstats/geomstats/blob/master/geomstats/riemannian_metric.py as `loss`. Some operations are using the shape of a tensor as parameter hence cannot be properly expanded to multi dimensional tensors. The way I solved it for now is defining a custom `tf.custom_gradient` and nesting `map_fn` over batch and element counts, but it is terribly slow.

Comment: I see the point of the complexity here... So, the relevant comments are: 1 - Ideally, we should avoid any iterations (this has a terrible performance), if we could build the function with plain tensorflow/keras operations, the performance would be really really better.

Comment: 2 - Now, if iterating is unavoidable (because we can't translate the functions to regular operations), then it should only be possible in known dimensions (unfortunately the first dimension is unknown, unless you use a fixed batch size with `batch_shape` instead of `shape` in your inputs. Then you should be able to get the batch dimension with `K.int_shape(tensor)[0]`). Iteration should then use `for i in range(dimension)` and take slices `tensor[i]`, it's not possible to iterate the tensors directly.

Comment: 3 - Finally, and this is very important: I see the function transforms the tensors into `gs` objects. This will break the graph connection and make it impossible for Tensorflow to calculate the gradients (unless `gs`, which I don't know, is compatible somehow). One more point towards building the function yourself.